# trigger form submit as well as submit form on form submit

Tags: jquery

I have a submit handler.

```
$.('#form').submit();
```

I want to submit the form also when .trigger div has text

```
$('.trigger').text().length>0
```

.trigger is a div, where ajax call is made and has text. On changing select option .trigger text changes as well. Since .trigger takes sometime to load $('#form').trigger doesnt have all required value

I want form 
to be automatically submitted 
`($.('#form').trigger()) when $('.trigger').text().length>0` .

As well as normal form submit

```
`$.('#form').submit();
```

should also be present.

Comment: How are you changing the text of div and where and when ?

Comment: did you try my answer ?

Comment: Are you using AJAX to change `.trigger` text? Then you should put the length check in the AJAX callback function.

Comment: yes, but ajax call is in another js, since ajax is also being used for another page, which doesnt require form submit

Comment: Check my answer. How come its not working ?

Answer (score 0):

```
setInterval(function () {
    if ($('.trigger').text().length > 0) {
        $('#form').submit();
    }
}, 1000);
```

The above should do.